# Replacing the line of text if username is the same in text file?

Tags: vb.net

I'm saving a username and time stamp into a text file every time a user opens my application. I want to be able to open the text file and if the username already exist, replace the username/timestamp with current one. If so, possibly show how many times that person has also opened it as well. Here's my saving to my text file:

```
    Dim DomainInfo As Object
    Dim Username As String
    DomainInfo = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Username = DomainInfo.Username

    Dim path As String = "C:\myfolder"

    If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    Else
        Dim filename As String = "C:\myfolder\user.log"

        Dim sw As StreamWriter = AppendText(filename)
        sw.WriteLine(Now() & " " & Username)
        sw.Close()
        File.SetAttributes(filename, FileAttributes.Hidden)
    End If
```

Comment: Am I missing something here?  What is your question?  Is what you have not working?

Comment: go read the question again. If the same users open the application again, there will already be a time stamp in the text file with their name, i just want to replace the existing line of text with the current name/time stamp.

Comment: I've read it a bunch of times.  So what is wrong with what you have?  What *specifically* do you want from us?

Comment: it only adds another line of username/time stamp to file. If i was the user, and i used it three times, i will have three name/time stamp in the file. What i want to do is only replace my username/time stamp not have three.

Comment: You can't replace text in a text file.  You will have to write the whole thing again.

Comment: you can't read a text file line by line and if one of the line contains the username then replace that line of text and save text file?

Comment: No, that's not how it works.  You can only read a text file or write to a text file.  You can't do both at the same time.  Writing comes in two flavors: replacing the whole contents, or appending to the contents.  Therefore, to achieve what you want, you will need to 1.) read the entire file into memory, 2.) perform your operations in memory (i.e. replace blah blah), and 3.) write the whole thing back out to file.

Comment: Please explain, this file contains only the date and the username or also other info that you want to preserve? And if you want to preserve it, how big is this file?

Comment: how do i achieve the find and replace @roryap

Comment: @Steve that is the only infor in the text file but then there could be multiply users's time stamp in there as well.

Comment: You would just loop through the lines in memory and once you reach the one you want, operate on that line.

Comment: Does the UserName contains spaces?

Comment: yes it contains spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read from the text file into your program and change the required text and write it all back into the text file from scratch

```
 Dim lstTextFile As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList
 For each line In lstTextFile
     'edit your line here if meets requirements, an if statement would probably work
 Next

'the below line writes it back to the file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, lstTextFile.ToArray, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

Updated example using your code:

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\myfolder\user.log"
Dim lstTextFile As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList
For each line In lstTextFile
    If line.contains(username) then 
        lstTextFile.remove(line)
    End If
Next

lstTextFile.add(Now() & " " & Username)

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, lstTextFile.ToArray, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

Comment: examples on how to achieve this?

Comment: I've used a if statement inside the for each loop and used if line.contains(username) then line.remove(line) but that doesn't seem to be working, it's still added to the text file.

Comment: it would be lstTextFile.remove(line) not line.remove(line) as line is the current record you are looking at in the list lstTextFile

Comment: is there any need for closing the last line of code above or close the document? I have it check the file if it contains the username, if not it exit out of the for loop and then it runs that last line of code then it is suppose to run my code in my post to add the username, but it skips my code on your last line.

Comment: You could run the for each loop and remove the line if its the same user. Then after the for each loop, run your code, but add it to the list instead and then use the last line to write it all to the file.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how i would do it using your code

Comment: For some odd reasons, it's not saving it back to file correctly. I still see the old username time stamp after running the code. It removes and all but not saving right.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and stepping through it to see whats happening, see if it actually removes it in the for each loop?

Comment: oops, i didn't have a text file, i had a file.log file thats why it didn't do justice. thanks.

Comment: Been doing some testing, i think the for each loop should actually be `For x As Integer = (lstTextFile.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            If lstTextFile(x).Contains(Username) Then
                lstTextFile.RemoveAt(x)
            End If
        Next `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove them:

```
Dim Username = Environment.Username
Dim filename = "C:\myfolder\user.log"
Dim linesremoved = 0

If File.Exists(filename) Then
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    Dim lookup = lines.ToLookup(Function(l) l.EndsWith(Username))
    linesremoved = lookup(True).Count ' the number of lines that end with the Username

    If linesremoved > 0 Then File.WriteAllLines(filename, lookup(False).ToArray)
End If
```

Comment: you have an error on lookup - string cannot be converted to integer.

Comment: `Username` has to be set to the user name that you want to remove, and also check if `linesremoved` is 0.

Comment: this works too but the other answer does it now. thanks